# How to change TFS folder mappings without performing get?

Tags: tfs

I just want to move the folder where all of my projects are stored. It seems to be able to do this, I need to re-map the folders which performs a get and download all of the files. I don't want to lose progress on files that I currently have checked out and am working on.

Is there a way to simply rename the mappings for my TFS projects without performing a get?

Comment: Hi rgorr, sorry it's not able to do this without Get operation. Do you have any other concern? If my reply helped or gave a right direction. Appreciate for *marking it as an answer* will also help others in the community.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need to perform a "Get" on the branch root level to update project associations.

> A workspace mapping creates a client-side folder into which all files
>   and subfolders in the Team Foundation version control server folder
>   are **retrieved when you execute a tf get operation.**

[*Source Link*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/workfold-command?view=azure-devops#remarks)

If you want to suspend your work,  you could shelve your pending changes to a shelveset. Then change workspace mapping. Finally unshelve your shelveset. You could continue to work on them. More details please refer: [Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=azure-devops)